# Verify that a valid session token exists before making a WCF service call multiple browsers with shared session

Tags: wcf, wif, federated-identity

Using WIF, WCF within a Silverlight client accessing backend WCF services.
The application sign out uses Federation Authentication Module SignOut method which in turn calls Session Authentication Module (SAM) DeleteSessionTokenCookie for the local RP (Relying Party) sign out. A sign out to the the IP (Issuing Party) is subsequently called. All of this functions as expected.

I have come across the following multiple browser scenario relating to shared session that results in a “remote server returned an error not found” issue. If IE's "New Session" is used this is not an issue.

Steps:

1. Use IE shortcut to open a browser instance 1, navigate to application and login.
2. Use IE shortcut to open a browser instance 2, navigate to application and login.
3. Log out of application in browser instance 2.
4. Perform any operation that requires communication to the server. e.g. Log out of application browser instance 1.

Result: “remote server returned an error not found” exception

Is it possible to detect that the WIF token has been deleted prior to making a WCF call in browser instance 1 and so notify the user. The IdentityModelServiceAuthorizationManager.CheckAccessCore (OperationContext) method is being used to verify service access (authorization) prior to making any WCF service calls. Would it be possible to access and evaluate session token related information at this time? Or is there another approach that can be used?